# Problem with fetching data from SQLite in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I was following [this tutroial about using your own SQLite database](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/). I did these steps as described in the tutorial:

- Preparing my database
- Copying the same EXACT `DataBaseHelper` class to my project package. You can see the class code [there](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)
- Then, I just added one method to the `DataBaseHelper` class which is `fetchData`. It is simply fetching a whole table with the given name:

  ```
  public Cursor fetchData(String table) {
  String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {"*"};
  return myDataBase.query(table, null, null, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
  }
  ```
- After that, in one of my activity classes I did this:

  ```
  DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
  myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

  try { 

      myDbHelper.createDataBase();

  } catch (IOException ioe) {

      throw new Error("Unable to create database");

  }
  try {

      myDbHelper.openDataBase();

  } catch (SQLException sqle) {

      throw sqle;

  }

  TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
  try {
  //I will use my method to fetch a table named: myTable      
      Cursor c = myDbHelper.fetchData("myTable"); 
      if((Object)c.getCount() != null)
          txt.setText(c.getCount());
      else
          txt.setText("null");
  } catch(Exception e) {
      txt.setText("error");

  }
  ```

However, I keep getting 'error' in the TextView. Is there a problem in my way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is nothing related to SQLite. It was silly mistake :-\

The error is in the second line here:

```
if((Object)c.getCount() != null)
    txt.setText(c.getCount());
```

It must be like this:

```
    txt.setText(""+c.getCount());
```

the `setText()` method accepts a `ChaSequence` and the `getCount()` method returns `Integer` which are not in compatible type. you can work around that tha easy way, by adding empty string :)

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Cursor fetchData(String table) {
     return myDataBase.query(table, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Seems you got wrong idea about the `selectionArgs` parameter. In [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), it says:

> You may include ?s in selection, which
>   will be replaced by the values from
>   selectionArgs, in order that they
>   appear in the selection. The values
>   will be bound as Strings.

Comment: That was my first trial but it didn't work. I tried this instead and got the same. Thanks for your try.

Comment: As your app is going to the `catch` part, check what exception you are getting.

Comment: I figured it out :) See my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't answer before 7 hours :(

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to cast an int as an Object, then comparing the cast value to null. I would say that you code is likely to break right there.